# Access the ASP.Net LoginControl Password field through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, passwords, login-control

I'm using the ASP.Net LoginControl for user validation:

```
   <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox id="UserName" runat="server" class="inD"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="UserNameWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="UserName" WatermarkText="Username" WatermarkCssClass="weD inD"/>
            <asp:TextBox id="Password" runat="server" class="inD" textMode="Password" onfocus="passwordFocus()" onblur="passwordBlur()"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="PasswordWatermarkExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Password" WatermarkText="Password" WatermarkCssClass="weD inD"/>
            <asp:button id="Login" CommandName="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" class="btL" BorderStyle="None"></asp:button>
            <br />
            <asp:Checkbox id="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me"></asp:Checkbox>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" Text="*"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" Text="*"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            <asp:Literal id="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
```

Now I would like to access the password box (ID: Password) through JavaScript. I tried

```
document.getElementById('Password');
```

but this doesn't work.
Thanks for any advice,

Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET (depending on which version of the framework you're on) likes to mangle client ids.  I've gotten around this in the past like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var passwordId = '<%= Password.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Seems kind of dirty, but it works!

**Edit:**

I see that you are in a LoginForm control.  Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var passwordId = '<%= ((TextBox)LoginForm.FindControl("Password")).ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm getting a compiler error, saying, that "Password is not declared". The code looks like this:
inD1 = document.getElementById('<%= Password.ClientID %>'); Have you got an idea, of what goes wrong? Thank you, Alexander